# PyInstaller in Mac os X Mavericks

Tags: python, macos, pyinstaller

I have a problem with PyInstaller on Mac OS X, my Python version is 2.7 and I installed PyInstaller with pip. When I type `pyinstaller` in the command line, this error is returned:

```
$ pyinstaller
-bash: pyinstaller: command not found
```

I have PyInstaller installed in Windows from pip, and it works fine.

Comment: Can you show the pip install log in Mac?

Answer (score 1):

this might be a little late, but you should install the zip file, extract the zip. Open the terminal and go to that directory, move the py files that you want to use pyinstaller for, and use this command:

```
$python pyinstaller.py yourfile.py
```

or if it's a GUI, use the --window extension:

```
$python pyinstaller.py --window yourfile.py
```

Hope this helped!